# How can I enable integrated authentication in Chrome headless

Tags: windows-authentication, google-chrome-headless

I am using Chrome headless for testing purposes but I don't know how to make it perform integrated authentication.

I have just tried `WebUI.authenticate("localhost", "my name", "my password", 10)` but it hasn't worked.